# Performance gap between spring data jpa and hibernate - jHipster

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm trying to find out why my jHipster app is so slow when querying a database.

This is one of my services using spring-data's `PagingAndSortingRepository`

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Center> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all Centers");

    return centerRepository.findAll(pageable);        
}
```

I've used JHipsters' `LoggingAspect` and added a timer to log the performance of each method.

```
@Around("loggingPointcut()")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = null;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    }
    try {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() [took {} ms] with result = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), stopwatch.elapsed(MILLISECONDS), result);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.error("Illegal argument: {} in {}.{}()", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

        throw e;
    }
}
```

I configured hibernate to generate the statictics:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

If I change the log-levels of `org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl` and `org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener` I see the following logs:

```
2016-10-13 11:00:00,640 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] LoggingAspect: Enter: com.fluidda.broncholab.service.CenterService.findAll() with argument[s] = [Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: id: ASC]]
2016-10-13 11:00:00,643 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] CenterService: Request to get all Centers
2016-10-13 11:00:02,238 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ConcurrentStatisticsImpl: HHH000117: HQL: select count(generatedAlias0) from Center as generatedAlias0, time: 1ms, rows: 1
2016-10-13 11:00:02,241 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ConcurrentStatisticsImpl: HHH000117: HQL: select generatedAlias0 from Center as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.id asc, time: 2ms, rows: 3
2016-10-13 11:00:02,242 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] LoggingAspect: Exit: com.fluidda.broncholab.service.CenterService.findAll() [took 1601 ms] with result = Page 1 of 1 containing com.fluidda.broncholab.domain.Center instances
2016-10-13 11:00:02,243 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-8] StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    568512 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    92324 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    992105 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    34717 nanoseconds spent performing 3 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    2943 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

If you take a look at the timings (not the timestamp when the item was logged), you'll see a big difference between:

- ConcurrentStatisticsImpl: time: **2ms**, rows: 3
- LoggingAspect: [took **1601 ms**]
- StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: **992105 nanoseconds** spent executing 2 JDBC statements;

The strange is, that these performance issue's do **not** occur all the time! This is the dropwizard statistic:

```
Service name                                Count   Mean    Min p50 p75 p95 p99 Max
....web.rest.CenterResource.getAllCenters   5       13      10  16  16  16  16  1,612
```

Does anyone know what may cause these performance drops?

Does anyone know how I can investigate any further?

Comment: If you have a 1 second gap, couldn't you manually take a thread dump (jstack or kill -3 or your JVM process) ? Or use a profiler, on such an important gap, you might even be able to spot what is going on using java mission control, just have a few hundred calls, and take a recording of the whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding extra logging, and not using an ASYNC logger, I've find out, the server was losing time parsing the HQL.

I've created another question about this: [Hibernate QueryTranslatorImpl HQL AST parsing performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257688/hibernate-querytranslatorimpl-hql-ast-parsing-performance)