# Hibernate QueryTranslatorImpl HQL AST parsing performance

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm facing performance issues executing standard spring-data-jpa `findAll` queries using `@NamedEntityGraph`

When I examine the logs, I see the following statements:

```
2016-10-26 09:46:25,681 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] CriteriaQueryImpl: Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Patient as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.id asc
2016-10-26 09:46:25,681 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] CriteriaQueryImpl: Rendered criteria query -> select count(generatedAlias0) from Patient as generatedAlias0
2016-10-26 09:46:25,681 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SQL: select count(patient0_.id) as col_0_0_ from patient patient0_
2016-10-26 09:46:25,682 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Loader: Result row: 
2016-10-26 09:46:25,682 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ConcurrentStatisticsImpl: HHH000117: HQL: select count(generatedAlias0) from Patient as generatedAlias0, time: 0ms, rows: 1
2016-10-26 09:46:25,682 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] QueryTranslatorImpl: parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.fluidda.broncholab.domain.Patient as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.id asc
2016-10-26 09:46:27,340 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] QueryTranslatorImpl: --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'fluidda'
    |  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'broncholab'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'domain'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Patient'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[ORDER] Node: 'order'
       +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
       |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
       \-[ASCENDING] Node: 'asc'

2016-10-26 09:46:27,340 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ErrorCounter: throwQueryException() : no errors
2016-10-26 09:46:27,340 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] HqlSqlBaseWalker: select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
2016-10-26 09:46:27,341 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FromElement: FromClause{level=1} : com.fluidda.broncholab.domain.Patient (generatedAlias0) -> patient0_
```

There is a big gap between 2 `QueryTranslatorImpl` log statements: **almost 2 seconds?!**

When looking in the source code, I don't see anything special (hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final)

```
private HqlParser parse(boolean filter) throws TokenStreamException, RecognitionException {
    // Parse the query string into an HQL AST.
    final HqlParser parser = HqlParser.getInstance( hql );
    parser.setFilter( filter );

    LOG.debugf( "parse() - HQL: %s", hql );
    parser.statement();

    final AST hqlAst = parser.getAST();

    final NodeTraverser walker = new NodeTraverser( new JavaConstantConverter() );
    walker.traverseDepthFirst( hqlAst );

    showHqlAst( hqlAst );

    parser.getParseErrorHandler().throwQueryException();
    return parser;
}
```

What is the problem here? It is a very basic HQL, why does it takes so long?

Is it possible to cache these HQL AST parsing?

Answer (score 4):

The HQL query plans are cached, for performance considerations. You can control the query plan cache using the following two configuration properties:

- `hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size` = 2048 (default value)
- `hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size` = 128 (default value)

Try increasing the [`hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-query-plan-cache/) value to a value that's appropriate for your data access patterns.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Does it mean that executing a HQL-query will always be slow the first time?

Comment: This is the same with any database query. When you first execute a query, the DB has to generate an execution plan. Some DBs might cache the plan (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server), so the first execution is slower. The same is true for HQL queries. The first time they execute, they will be slower. But if you cache the HQL plan properly, then all the other executions will be fast.

Comment: I did not mention it before, but I do not see a HQL parsing time of 2 seconds all the time. Most of the time, it takes only about 30 ms to parse the HQL (for the same query, of course). Any idea why parsing time is not consistent?

Comment: That only happens when the cache is full and older entries get evicted.

Comment: The current parser also suffers from some inherent performance problems.  It was our first foray into Antlr and we made some bad decisions (in retrospect) in certain areas.  That said, we are rewriting query parsing from scratch for 6.0 - stay tuned

Comment: After some more debugging, I've noticed, QueryPlanCache is NOT used when executing QueryImpl.list() with an EntityGraphQueryHint!!!? Perfomance was the reason for adding EntityGraph annotations, and now it turns out, a caching opportunity is not used by this

Comment: You need to open a Jira issue for this.